# Install FM Radio Module on Xperia E Dual flashed with Custom ROM

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, sony-xperia

Can anyone please help me with the procedure to install [FM Radio](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/03/07/fm-radio-module-released-as-open-source-and-sensor-hal-updated/) in my rooted Xperia E Dual flashed with [Nexboost ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/development/rom-nexboost-cm11-camera-t2852519)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread on XDA forums. They are providing an app (which is already available in Play Store) named SpiritFM which uses phone's inbuilt antenna for radio (also via internet if required). Go to XDA dev page and use search string *spirit fm* or [Click Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/sitesearch.php?q=spirit%20fm).

Comment: This is not working with my phone

Comment: Then you're not gonna find any stock fm radio app anywhere. Probably you should look into the internet radios like TuneIn, rad.io etc